# Get remote IP address in JavaFX desktop app

Tags: java, spring, javafx, httprequest, ip-address

I need to obtain the remote IP address of a user in my JavaFX desktop app. I am using Spring to deal with things such as authentication (my program uses database connection). I do know how to get IP address from http request when using Java Servlet, the problem is I don't have one in my app. I considered using some kind of website that checks IP, and simply getting the content of the html parsed to a string, but I have to do everything locally / independent from any external source.

I appreciate any kind of help, thanks in advance

EDIT: Some additional info that might help: I am not using sockets, my app is supposed to be used by end user, and only connection it has is the connection with MySQL database from which it gets some content. I need to retrieve the IP address of user at the moment of logging in, to put said IP address together with port to a particular table in my database.

Comment: I don't think you can get your external IP without getting it from an external source. Of course, someone might prove me wrong. Use http://icanhazip.com/ if you need that.

Comment: What @EpicPandaForce said; unless the machine running the app is directly receiving the IP you're looking for, this is essentially impossible. Due to the nature of network/port translation, it's impossible to know the untranslated IP without either querying an external source, or querying the router/firewall doing the translation (which no serious router/fw would support).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the only way to do this is to query an external source. You can fairly easily write some code to do this, e.g.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


public class RealIPScraper {
    private static final String URL_STRING = "http://www.realip.info/api/p/realip.php" ;

    private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\{\"IP\":\"(?<ip>.*)\"\\}");

    public static String getIP() throws IOException {
        URL url = new URL(URL_STRING);
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openConnection().getInputStream()))) {
            String content = String.join("\n", in.lines().collect(Collectors.toList()));
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
            if (matcher.matches()) {
                return matcher.group("ip");
            } else {
                return "No ip found";
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: is it possible to obtain port the same way you mentioned?

Comment: No... I'm not even sure that question makes sense. The code works by connecting to another (web) server. The port reported would merely be the port on that server to which you connected, which would be meaningless in terms of what you want to do.